# SQL optimization tips

Tags: sql

I am a beginner  to sql and have some performance problems with this query.
Any tips? The query is running on a huge database...

```
SELECT
                z_screenshots.guid,
                z_screenshots.player_name,
                z_screenshots.server,
                z_screenshots.map,
                z_screenshots.created,
                z_screenshots.uploaded,
                z_screenshots.uploader_id,
                z_screenshots.filesize
            FROM z_screenshots 
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT clients.guid
                FROM clients WHERE clients.id NOT IN (
                    SELECT clients.id
                    FROM clients
                    INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT client_id
                        FROM penalties
                        WHERE penalties.inactive = 0 AND(penalties.type = 'Ban' OR (penalties.type = 'TempBan' AND FROM_UNIXTIME(penalties.time_expire) > NOW()) )
                        GROUP BY penalties.client_id
                    ) penalties
                    ON clients.id = penalties.client_id
                )
            ) clients
            ON z_screenshots.guid = clients.guid

            ORDER BY z_screenshots.uploaded DESC
            LIMIT ?, ?;
```

Comment: Hint number 1 - `not in` is slow.  There are other options but you have to match the logic.  It also depends on your database engine which you didn't specify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise to rewrite your query.

```
SELECT
    s.guid,
    s.player_name,
    s.server,
    s.map,
    s.created,
    s.uploaded,
    s.uploader_id,
    s.filesize
FROM z_screenshots s 
INNER JOIN clients c ON s.guid = c.guid
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT client_id
    FROM penalties
    WHERE penalties.inactive = 0 
    AND (penalties.type = 'Ban' OR (penalties.type = 'TempBan' AND FROM_UNIXTIME(penalties.time_expire) > NOW()) )
) p ON c.id = p.client_id
WHERE p.client_id IS NULL;
ORDER BY s.uploaded DESC
LIMIT ?, ?;
```

When you don't have very much `client_id`, this query would also be okay:

```
SELECT
    s.guid,
    s.player_name,
    s.server,
    s.map,
    s.created,
    s.uploaded,
    s.uploader_id,
    s.filesize
FROM z_screenshots s 
INNER JOIN clients c ON s.guid = c.guid
WHERE c.id NOT IN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT client_id
    FROM penalties
    WHERE penalties.inactive = 0 
    AND (penalties.type = 'Ban' OR (penalties.type = 'TempBan' AND FROM_UNIXTIME(penalties.time_expire) > NOW()) )
)
ORDER BY s.uploaded DESC
LIMIT ?, ?;
```

Regarding indexes, it's hard to tell. `clients`, this doesn't sound like you have very much distinct values. An index is the better, the closer the result of this formula gets to 1.

```
COUNT(DISTINCT <column>) / COUNT(<column>)
```

Meaning, when you have 5 distinct values and 5000000 rows, MySQL (assuming because of your `LIMIT` clause) will think that it's cheaper to just read the entire table. If this is the case here, you might consider having an index on `z_screenshots.uploaded` instead, so that MySQL at least doesn't have to sort. Read about [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) to know when an index is chosen and which index it is.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your nice and quick answer! P.S. It is MYSQL(as you said)